# How to reinitiate/resend a request with $fetch like Axios?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a onResponseError interceptor in which I would like to resend the original request after updating its headers with a new valid token. With Axios this was possible like this:

```
const originalRequestConfig = error.config;
// [...] Update the headers
return $axios.request(originalRequestConfig);
```

How do I achieve this with $fetch?

I want to:

- Send a request
- When I get an error code 401, get another token
- Retry the very same request

This should not be an unusual scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
const { data, pending, error, refresh } = useFetch('/pages', {})
</script>

// @/composables/useCustomFetch.ts
import type { UseFetchOptions } from 'nuxt/app'
import { defu } from 'defu'

export function useCustomFetch<T> (url: string, options: UseFetchOptions<T> = {}) {
    const config = useRuntimeConfig()
    const { isSignedIn, getToken, setToken } = useAuthStore()

    const defaults: UseFetchOptions<T> = {
        baseURL: config.public.apiBaseUrl,
        key: url,
        server: false,
        retry: 1,
        retryStatusCodes: [401],
        retryDelay: 500, // can safely delete this

        onRequest({ options }) {
           options.headers = isSignedIn
              ? { Authorization: `Bearer ${getToken()}` } // send token
              : {}
        },

        async onResponseError({ response, options }) {
           if (response.status === 401) {
             await useFetch('/auth/refresh', {
               baseURL: config.public.apiBaseUrl,
               method: 'POST',
               server: false,
               credentials: 'include',

               onResponse({ response }) {
                 setToken(response._data.token) // store token
               },
         },
       )
      }
     }
    }

    const params = defu(options, defaults)

    return useFetch(url, params)
 }
```